# Java File Handling, what did I do wrong?

Tags: java, filehandle

Wrote up a basic file handler for a Java Homework assignment, and when I got the assignment back I had some notes about failing to catch a few instances:

- Buffer from file *could* have been null.
- File was not found
- File stream wasn't closed

Here is the block of code that is used for opening a file:

```
/**
 * Create a Filestream, Buffer, and a String to store the Buffer.
 */
FileInputStream fin = null;
BufferedReader buffRead = null;
String loadedString = null;

/** Try to open the file from user input */
try
{
    fin = new FileInputStream(programPath + fileToParse);
    buffRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));
    loadedString = buffRead.readLine();
    fin.close();
}
/** Catch the error if we can't open the file */
catch(IOException e)
{
    System.err.println("CRITICAL: Unable to open text file!");
    System.err.println("Exiting!");
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

The one comment I had from him was that `fin.close();` needed to be in a `finally` block, which I did not have at all. But I thought that the way I have created the try/catch it would have prevented an issue with the file not opening.

Let me be clear on a few things: This is not for a current assignment (not trying to get someone to do my own work), I have already created my project and have been graded on it. I did not fully understand my Professor's reasoning myself. Finally, I do not have a lot of Java experience, so I was a little confused why my `catch` wasn't good enough.

Comment: While it is important to close system resources in a long-running program (and of course it's good to practice doing it), it's kind of a moot point whether you close the file if you're going to call `System.exit` in your catch block.

Comment: @jasonmp85 That's what I thought, but yes it does look like he wanted us to have it marked up as if it would have kept running. That makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> - **Buffer from file *could* have been null.**

The file may be empty. That is, end-of-file is reach upon opening the file. `loadedString = buffRead.readLine()` would then have returned null.

Perhaps you should have fixed this by adding something like `if (loadedString == null) loadedString = "";`

> - **File was not found**

As explained in the documentation of the constructor of `FileInputStream(String)` it may throw a `FileNotFoundException`. You do catch this in your `IOException` clause (since `FileNotFoundException` *is an* `IOException`), so it's fine, but you could perhaps have done:

```
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    System.err.println("File not fonud!");
} catch (IOException ioex {
    System.err.println("Some other error");
}
```

> - **File stream wasn't closed**

You do call `fin.close()` which in normal circumstances closes the file stream. Perhaps he means that it's not *always* closed. The `readLine` could potentially throw an `IOException` in which case the `close()` is skipped. That's the reason for having it in a `finally` clause (which makes sure it gets called no matter what happens in the `try`-block. (*)

---

(*) As @mmyers correctly points out, putting the `close()` in a `finally` block will actually not be sufficient since you call `System.exit(-1)` in the `catch`-block. If that really is the desired behavior, you could set an error flag in the catch-clause, and exit after the finally-clause if this flag is set.

Comment: The finally clause won't get executed if there's an exception, because of the System.exit() in the catch block.

Comment: Technically though, the finalize-method of the FileInputStream *will* close the stream upon termination :-)

Comment: instead of this: 'if (loadedString == null) loadedString = "";' I would usually resort to StringUtils.stripToEmpty() using apache commons / lang http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#stripToEmpty%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: @seanizer: It's a school assignment.

Comment: Thanks! That made a lot of sense the way you explained it :)

Answer (score 3):

But what if your program threw an exception on the second or third line of your `try` block?

```
buffRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));
loadedString = buffRead.readLine();
```

By this point, a filehandle has been opened and assigned to `fin`. You could trap the exception but the filehandle would remain open.

You'll want to move the `fin.close()` statement to a `finally` block:

```
} finally {
    try {
        if (fin != null) {
            fin.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e2) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should add a `if (fin != null)` before you try to close it (in case that the file didn't exist).

Comment: or, again using apache commons (io in this case), write just one line: 'IOUtils.closeQuietly(fin);', this does exactly what you are doing in a lot less (local) code http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#closeQuietly%28java.io.InputStream%29

Answer (score 1):

Say `buffRead.readLine()` throws an exception, will your `FileInputStream` ever be closed, or will that line be skipped? The purpose of a `finally` block is that even in exceptional circumastances, the code in the `finally` block will execute.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of other errors which may happen other than opening the file.

In the end you may end up with a fin which is defined or not which you have to protect against null pointer errors, and do not forget that closing the file can throw a new exception.

My advice is to capture this in a separate routine and let the IOExceptions fly out of it :

something like

```
private String readFile() throws IOException {
  String s;
  try {
    fin = new FileInputStream(programPath + fileToParse);
    buffRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));
    s = buffRead.readLine();
    fin.close();
  } finally {
    if (fin != null {
       fin.close()
    }
  }
  return s
}
```

and then where you need it :

```
try {
   loadedString = readFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
   // handle issue gracefully
}
```

Comment: The `finally` block is executed regardless of whether an exception was raised.  Therefore, you have a redundant `fin.close()` under normal circumstances.  The one in the `try` block can be removed.

Comment: gee, there is an apache commons solution to almost every problem on this page. Use FileUtils.readFileToString(file), it's much shorter and you can resue it. http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString(java.io.File)